# How do you use the `secondary` kwarg to fit this situation in SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a situation where a user can belong to many courses, and a course can contain many users.  I have it modeled in SqlAlchemy like so:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class Course(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'courses'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    archived = Column(DateTime)


class CourseJoin(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'course_joins'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    # Foreign keys
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    course_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('courses.id'))
```

In the system, we have the ability to "archive" a course.  This is marked by a datetime field on the course model.  I would like to give the `User` model a relationship called `course_joins` that only contains CourseJoins where the respective `Course` hasn't been archived.  I'm trying to use the `secondary` kwarg to accomplish this like so:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    course_joins = relationship('CourseJoin',
                                secondary='join(Course, CourseJoin.course_id == Course.id)',
                                primaryjoin='and_(CourseJoin.user_id == User.id,'
                                                 'Course.archived == None)',
                                order_by='CourseJoin.created')
```

However I'm getting this error:

```
InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers.  Original exception was: FROM expression expected
```

I believe this is the exact usecase for the `secondary` kwarg of `relationship()`, but I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

If you really just have many-to-many relationship (plus `created`) column, I think the right way to define the relationship is:

```
courses = relationship(
    'Course',
    secondary='course_joins',
    primaryjoin='users.c.id == course_joins.c.user_id',
    secondaryjoin='and_(courses.c.id == course_joins.c.course_id, courses.c.archived == None)',
    order_by='course_joins.c.created',
    viewonly=True,
)
```

and use it like:

```
u1 = User(courses=[Course()])
session.add(u1)
u2 = User(courses=[Course(archived=datetime.date(2013, 1, 1))])
session.add(u2)
```

Otherwise, just drop the `secondary` completely and add your other condition to `primaryjoin`:

```
courses = relationship(
    'CourseJoin',
    primaryjoin=\
    'and_(users.c.id == course_joins.c.user_id, '
    'courses.c.id == course_joins.c.course_id, '
    'courses.c.archived == None)',
    order_by='course_joins.c.created',
)
```

Comment: kk cool, is there any way I can do this while still returning course_joins?  I have other areas of the code that rely on that attribute.